# Is there an R function that splits the columns of a data.frame and cbind them together?

Tags: r, cbind

I have a data frame and a column with over 1.000.0000 values. I know that I need to take values from 1:30.000 then, 30.000:60.000 and so on, and cbind this parts, to get multiple columns out of the original one. How do I do that?

Comment: So you have a data.frame of one column and want to end up with a data.frame of 1.000.000 rows.

Comment: You can create a matrix from a single column (vector) with wanted number of rows: `matrix(iris$Sepal.Length, 50)`. Here you *cbind* one column by 50. In the end you can create a data frame: `as.data.frame(matrix(iris$Sepal.Length, 50))`

Comment: My data frame has multiple columns, but one of them, let's say data.frame$ID, is huge, and divide it in 50 equal parts, 1:30.000, 30.000:60.000 and so on.... now part 1:30.000 needs to become a column itself, and the columns that follows needs to be 30.000:60.000 ....

Comment: I will try that PoGibas thank you. Will check now :)

Answer (score 0):

We can `split` the column into a `list` and `cbind`

```
n <- 30000
out <- do.call(cbind, split(df1$ID, as.integer(gl(nrow(df1), n, nrow(df1)))))
```

---

If the `split`s are not of equal length, we can use `cbind.fill` from `rowr`

```
library(rowr)
out <- do.call(cbind.fill, split(df1$ID, as.integer(gl(nrow(df1), n, nrow(df1)))))
```

Comment: what's the df1?

Comment: oh sorry it's my df

Comment: @user11465312  IN that case change `df1` to `df`.  In the comments above, you said `data.frame$ID`, so I was not sure about the object identifier

Comment: I get the  Error: cannot allocate vector of size 220.3 Gb

Comment: @user11465312  That is a memory issue.  You may need to increase the memory